# Symfony 2.3 cache clear IOException

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm trying to clear my cache on my local server using `php app/console cache:clear` and get the following error:

`[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
Cannot rename because the target "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\dev" already exist.`

I have had that problem for the second time. I fixed it by manually clearing the cache, which contained a **30Go dev_old** folder.

How can I properly clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proper rights to clear the cache.

Also, there is no harm in deleting the files manually. Just remove the folders.

But, there will be no cache warmup afterwards if you do it that way.

Comment: Well I never had any problem before so I figure I have the proper rights still. Should I run the cmd as administrator?

Comment: I'd say you should not have to. But your cmd should own the rights to manipulate your sf directories

Comment: Mmmm, you might be right about the rights. Randomly stumbled upon this error: `The directory ../dev/annotations is not writable. Both the webserver and the console user need access. You can manage access rights for multiple users with "chmod +a".` but I cannot reproduce that error again. Will look up the windows chmod equivalent.